# Couldn't update the new key in data into database (select using ID)

Tags: php, mysqli

This is the table I calling from database.
[image]

When I click on the edit button, it redirect me to this page (This is edit page) :

[image]

the data that shows in the text field is base on user ID. But when I click on the update button, the data doesn't update to the database.

Code below is how I grab the table data based on ID and display it in the text field in edit page :

```
<div id="table">
<div id="title">
<a>EDIT USER DETAILS</a>
</div>

<?php
        if( isset($_GET['userId']) )
        {
            $id = $_GET['userId'];
            $catchsql = "SELECT * FROM tbluser WHERE userId='$id'";
            $res= mysqli_query($con,$catchsql);
            $row= mysqli_fetch_array($res);
        }
        else {
            echo"Data Not Found !";
        }

?>

<form action="edit.php" method="POST">
<div id ="newform">
NAME: <input type="text" name="newname" value="<?php echo $row['userNm']; ?>" style="background: #fff; color:#000;"/>
FULL NAME:<input type="text" name="newfullname" value="<?php echo$row['userFullNm']; ?>" style="background: #fff; color:#000;"/><br />
<br>
EMAIL:<input type="text" name="newemail" value="<?php echo$row['userEmail']; ?>" style="background: #fff; color:#000;"/>
CONTACT:<input type="text" name="newcontact" value="<?php echo$row['userPhone']; ?>" style="background: #fff; color:#000;"/><br />
<br>
USER LEVEL: <input type="text" name="newlevel" value="<?php echo$row['userLvlId']; ?>" style="background: #fff; color:#000;"/>
STATUS:<input type="text" name="newstatus" value="<?php echo$row['userStatus']; ?>" style="background: #fff; color:#000; "/><br />
</form>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<a href ="user.php"><input type="button" name="SUBMIT" value="UPDATE" action="update.php" style="font-size:16px;text-align:center; border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0.5px; border-bottom-width: 0.5px; border-left-width: 0.5px; width: "></a>
</div>
```

Here is my code for update :

```
    if( isset($_POST['newname']) || isset($_POST['newfullname']) || isset($_POST['newemail']) || isset($_POST['newcontact']) || isset($_POST['newlevel']) || isset($_POST['newstatus']))
{
    $newName = $_POST['newname'];
    $newfullname= $_POST['newfullname'];
    $newemail = $_POST['newemail'];
    $newcontact = $_POST['newcontact'];
    $newlevel = $_POST['newlevel'];
    $newstatus = $_POST['newstatus'];
    $id      = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "UPDATE tbluser SET userNm='$newName', userFullNm=$newfullname, userEmail=$newemail, userPhone=$newcontact, userLvlId=$newlevel, userStatus=$newstatus WHERE userId='$id'";
    $res     = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not update".mysql_error());


}
?>
```

Do ask me if the information about my question that I provide is not clear. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions

1. Remove anchor tag it redirecting page without data to user.php
2. Also remove action from update input and keep type as submit and make sure form tag have right file name in action.
3. You should use && not || to check post variables.
4. Space b/w echo and php variables at all place.

   'i.e echo $row['userPhone'];'
5. Change query as other suggest, use quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try $sql = "UPDATE tbluser SET userNm='$newName', userFullNm='$newfullname', userEmail='$newemail', userPhone='$newcontact', userLvlId='$newlevel', userStatus='$newstatus' WHERE userId='$id'";

I put the user input php variables in single quotes. Also, you may want to look into using mysqli as mysql is deprecated, prevent again sql injection and use prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

Change the $catchsql to this:

```
$catchsql = "SELECT * FROM tbluser WHERE userId=".$id;
```

Change the $sql to this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tbluser SET userNm='".$newName."', userFullNm='".$newfullname."', userEmail='".$newemail."', userPhone='".$newcontact."', userLvlId='".$newlevel."', userStatus='".$newstatus."' WHERE userId=".$id;
```

Comment: Can i know what is the difference with '.' and without '.' ? The code is work in both way.

Comment: the one with '.' means your concatenating the value of each variable in your query. for example the value of $newName is "Chi Yang" the result query string of your original code will be "UPDATE tbluser SET userNm=$newName" instead of "UPDATE tbluser SET userNm = 'Chi Yang'" which the correct one.